# SSRS IIF Condition

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

i have one report where multiple condition going to apply 
like 100%
75%
and 50%

i used background colour condition

```
=iif(count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "8" and lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime")
= "100%" ,"Green","Red") and iif(
 count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value,Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "6" and lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime")
= "75%" ,"Green","Red") and iif(
count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "4" and lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime")
= "50%" ,"Green","Red")
```

i'm getting no colour please let me know what im doing worng as im new in SSRS Thanks

```
=Switch(Fields!Date.Value >= CDate("01/05/" & Str(Year(Parameters!StartDate.Value))) and Fields!Date.Value <= CDate("01/10/" & Str(Year(Parameters!EndDate.Value))) and
 count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "8"
and lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime") = "100%",
"Green",
Fields!Date.Value >= CDate("01/11/" & Str(Year(Parameters!StartDate.Value))) and Fields!Date.Value <= CDate("30/04/" & Str(Year(Parameters!EndDate.Value))) and
count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "4"
and lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime") = "100%",
"Green",
Fields!Date.Value >= CDate("01/05/" & Str(Year(Parameters!StartDate.Value))) and Fields!Date.Value <= CDate("01/10/" & Str(Year(Parameters!EndDate.Value))) and
count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value,Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "6"
and lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime") = "75%",
"Green",
Fields!Date.Value >= CDate("01/11/" & Str(Year(Parameters!StartDate.Value))) and Fields!Date.Value <= CDate("30/04/" & Str(Year(Parameters!EndDate.Value))) and
count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "3"
and lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime") = "75%",
"Green",

 Fields!Date.Value >= CDate("01/05/" & Str(Year(Parameters!StartDate.Value))) and Fields!Date.Value <= CDate("01/10/" & Str(Year(Parameters!EndDate.Value))) and
count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "4"
and lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime") = "50%" ,
"Green",
Fields!Date.Value >= CDate("01/11/" & Str(Year(Parameters!StartDate.Value))) and Fields!Date.Value <= CDate("30/04/" & Str(Year(Parameters!EndDate.Value))) and
count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "2"
and lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime") = "50%",
"Green",
true,"Red"
 )
```

Comment: Are you grouping by EMPNO in this report by chance?

Comment: nope .......... im grouping by assessores names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were letting the flow fall through the wrong way. I modified your formatting for clarity.

```
=iif(
    lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime")= "100%"
    and    
    (
        (
            IS_SUMMER() 
            AND 
            count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "8" 
        )
        OR
        (
            IS_WINTER()
            AND
            count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "4"     
        )
    ),
    "Green"

    ,iif(
        lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime")= "75%"
        and    
        (
            (
                IS_SUMMER() 
                AND 
                count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "6" 
            )
            OR
            (
                IS_WINTER()
                AND
                count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "3"     
            )
        ),
        "Green"

        ,iif(
            lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime")= "50%"
            and
            (
                (
                    IS_SUMMER() 
                    AND 
                    count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "6" 
                 )
                 OR
                 (
                    IS_WINTER()
                    AND
                    count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "3"     
                  )
            ),
            "Green"

            ,"Red"
        )
    )
 )
```

**Updated with extra fields.**

At this point you can see how **horrible** this is getting. It is hard on the eyes and hard to maintain and reuse. There are two ways to clean this up.

**1. Use a function in your code to set the color -**

```
textbox1.BackgroundColor=Code!MyFunctionToEvaluate(Percent,Number)
```

**2. Use Calculated Fields -**

```
IIF(
    Fields!CALCPercent.Value=100 AND 
    (
        (Fields!CALCIsSummer.Value AND Fields!CALCCount=8)
        OR
        (Fields!CALCIsWinter.Value AND Fields!CALCCount=6)
     )
    ...
)
```

Here is a function you can put in your Report|Options|Code window.

```
Public Function CalculateColor(percentage As String, count As String, Season As String) AS String    

    Dim Result As String = "Red"

    If(percentage="100%") Then
        Result = "Gree"
    Else If(percentage="75%") Then
        Result = "Gree"
    Else If (percentage="50%") Then
        Result="Green"
    EndIf

    return Result

End Function
```

Once that compiles (I did not check syntax) then you can assign the result to a textbox's BackgroundColor.

```
textbox.BackgroundCode=<Expression> =Code.CalculateColor(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"),count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime")),GET_SEASON())
```

Comment: thanks one more thing i need to add in this expersiion if     
 
is there any way where i put one more condition if 100% (8 per month for the summer 1st May – 31st Oct) (4 per month in the winter- 1st Nov – 30th April) 75% (6 per month for the summer 1st May – 31st Oct) (3 per month in the winter- 1st Nov – 30th April) 50% (4 per month for the summer 1st May – 31st Oct) (2 per month in the winter- 1st Nov – 30th April)

Comment: I updated with your requirements, however, to reduce clutter you might want to look into calculated fields.

Comment: how can i do that as im niew in SSRS

Comment: I added an example of how to use a function to reduce code clutter.

Comment: can't i use like this .. Check my Question >??

Comment: If it works for you then use it. Switch statements are certainly easier to read for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Switch instead:

```
=Switch(
  count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "8"
  and lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime") = "100%",
  "Green",
  count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value,Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "6"
  and lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime") = "75%" ,
  "Green",
  count(lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime"))>= "4"
  and lookup(Fields!Assessors_Staff_ID.Value,Fields!EMPNO.Value, Fields!SINFO.Value, "FullTime") = "50%" ,
  "Green",
  true,"Red"
)
```

It will work if you have the correct grouping settings for the calculations you are performing in each conditional.

Comment: is there any way where i put one more condition if 
100% (8 per month for the summer 1st May – 31st Oct) (4 per month in the winter- 1st Nov – 30th April)
75% (6 per month for the summer 1st May – 31st Oct) (3 per month in the winter- 1st Nov – 30th April)
50% (4 per month for the summer 1st May – 31st Oct) (2 per month in the winter- 1st Nov – 30th April)

Comment: @Skorpion, if you mean dinamically change the condition, you will need to calculate it somewhere (maybe a calculated field or a hidden parameter) else and then reference that calculation in the conditional.

Comment: how can i do that as im niew in SSRS ??